Application of $k$-forms to differential equations
I was presented with a problem that, in my view, is somewhat difficult, and it relates $k$-forms to systems of differential equations.
Consider the ellipsoid, given by
$$f(u, v)=(a\sin(u) \cos(v), b \sin(u) \sin (v), c \cos(u)) \quad 0 \leq u \leq \pi, \quad 0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$$
and consider the 2 form in $\Bbb R$ given by $w=dx-zdy$
the idea is to consider the kernel of the form $w$ at each point of the ellipsoid, in order to generate two intersecting planes that give me a straight line (as shown in the image).

To obtain such line segments I think it is enough to find the inner product of the normal vectors to each plane obtaining a director vector.
Now, here comes the objective and difficulty of the problem. The idea is to find a system of differential equations that gives a solution to this directional field, and here lies the big question, how is this possible? It seems that from the associated vector field the system is taken, conformed by the derivatives of the component functions and it would look like this
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dt}=abc \cos^2(t)sin(t) \\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}=ab \cos(t) \sin(t) \\
\frac{dz}{dt}= c \sin^2 (t)(-bc \cos(t) \cos(v)-a \sin(v))
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
But solving something like this is certainly difficult, I think.
Any contribution on this problem that helps me to develop what I asked for (to develop the system of equations associated to the differential form on the ellipsoid) is really useful.
